# What's wrong with the syntax for this SQL statement in VBA access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

The code below returns a syntax error in Access VBA and I was using this same code in a query design which worked fine. I understand the SQL code can be different when in query design mode vs. VBA query but I can't identify how to make this code run without error in Access VBA.

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    MAX(CurrentWeek.WeekEnding) AS MaxOfWeekEnding, 
    CurrentWeek.NWA, CurrentWeek.[NWA Description], CurrentWeek.Plan 
FROM 
    CurrentWeek 
INNER JOIN 
    (tblNWABasic 
INNER JOIN 
    tblProjects ON tblNWABasic.ProjectID = tblProjects.ProjectID) ON CurrentWeek.NWA = tblNWABasic.NWA 
GROUP BY 
    CurrentWeek.NWA, CurrentWeek.[NWA Description], CurrentWeek.Plan 
HAVING 
    (((CurrentWeek.[NWA Description]) Like "*direct cite*")) 
ORDER BY 
    MAX(CurrentWeek.WeekEnding) DESC;
```

Comment: Is `CurrentWeek` a table or a query? If it's query, we'll need to see the query's definition as it might be actually causing problems.

Comment: CurrentWeek is a table. I figured it out and I'm going to adjust the code.

Answer (score 1):

The Direct Cite portion was missing brackets. Corrected code piece shown below:

```
Like " * [direct cite] * "))
```

The above code should've worked but what actually ended up working was:

```
Like ' *[direct cite]* '))
```

Comment: This makes no sense. It is inside a constant string - Access wouldn't care about brackets in there (at least it wouldn't cause a syntax error).

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be enclosed in double quotes `"` not blockquotes `“ “`.  You will also need to escape all double quotes by doubling them up in the query (e.g. change `"*direct cite*"` to `""*direct cite*""`.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Max(CurrentWeek.WeekEnding) AS MaxOfWeekEnding, CurrentWeek.NWA, CurrentWeek.[NWA Description], CurrentWeek.Plan FROM CurrentWeek INNER JOIN (tblNWABasic INNER JOIN tblProjects ON tblNWABasic.ProjectID = tblProjects.ProjectID) ON CurrentWeek.NWA = tblNWABasic.NWA GROUP BY CurrentWeek.NWA, CurrentWeek.[NWA Description], CurrentWeek.Plan HAVING (((CurrentWeek.[NWA Description]) Like ""*direct cite*"")) ORDER BY Max(CurrentWeek.WeekEnding) DESC;
```

---

This subroutine will simplify the process of escaping the quotes.  Simply copy the string to the Windows Clipboard, run the EscapeDoubleQuotesInClipboard and paste the new string into your code.

```
Sub EscapeDoubleQuotesInClipboard()
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .GetFromClipboard
        .SetText Replace(.GetText, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34))
        .PutInClipboard
    End With
End Sub
```